# Where can I set the Story Board ID for my View Controller in XCode 8?

Tags: swift, storyboard, xcode8

I am new to Swift and XCode and since Apple released the new XCode 8 Beta, I have a problem finding the input for the Story Board ID in the Identity Inspector from my View Controller!

Can you please help me?
Thanks

[It looks a bit different than the old version!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IliD3.png)

Answer (score 2):

select your view controlloer, now in Inspector bar click on third option i.e. Identity inspector there you can enter the storyBoard id of you viewcontroller

Comment: This could benefit from a screenshot. But if it is same as previous Xcode builds then why is OP under the impression that it is different in Xcode 8 beta?

Comment: I added a screenshot in my question above

Comment: you can set storyboard id for class UIViewController, currently u have selected the UIButton, in that screenshot...
Click on the the yellow icon above your view controller than check